# Why aren't my new files appearing in my GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

I have created a repository, now I have worked on about 5 source files but they dont appear online. How do I upload them/make them show online.

Secondly, how do I allow other people to use the repository? What I mean is, the project is a four-person thing so how do the others join and how do I control uploaded files?

Comment: http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/

Comment: thanks rafe but i have done all that..How do i add new files..i put it in the folder for the repo(local) but it didnt appear online..

Comment: @DaMainBoss It means that when you ask a question, you can accept an answer by clicking the little check-mark below the voting tools. You're supposed to accept the answer which solved your problem. If you've answered twelve questions and never accepted an answer, you aren't doing this; it's very unlikely that in 12 questions you've never found an acceptable answer to any of your problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to commit your changes locally before you end off with push to sync your repository with the one on github, e.g.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Some changes"
git push origin master
```

Comment: Oh my dazee now i know where i as making the mistake..after the commit i ddnt add the -m. Thanks a lot. I appreciate...When you make changes to the file, can you still view previuos versions. Am just tryna see if there is a version control system

Comment: Git is a version control system that has all the functionality you require, and more, and some sugar on the top, and a little cocktail berry as well, and some fireworks and a glass of champagne. This includes the basic feature of viewing any version of any file. But that is another question.

Comment: Wow thats cool... Am already enjoying it, don't have to be loosing changes anymore..thanks. I appreciate

Comment: @DaMainBoss If you omit the -m, git should open your default editor (generally Nano, Vim, or Emacs) to allow you to enter the commit message. And you should make the message descriptive of the update of course; "some changes" was just example text.

Comment: oh yeah it opened vim but i ddnt knw what i was supposed to do..thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to commit and push your changes for them to show up online. Assuming you have already followed the steps GitHub gives you to link your local repository to the remote master, this is accomplished with a simple

```
git add .
git commit
git push
```

And adding additional contributors isn't too tricky, just go to the project, click the Admin button in the upper right corner, click the Collaborators tab, and add their github accounts.

This is really a question that is easily answered by the wonderful git and github documentation. Check out http://help.github.com/ for all of this and more. StackOverflow is for questions about programming, not about how to set up repositories (and it also shouldn't be used for questions that can be easily answered by existing documentation).